# Lost md array after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: raid, mdadm

I got problem to assemble one of my arrays after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 which was created at the system before upgrade.
I have probably used a to high md number for the array, but in 14.04 it was no problem to create a array with name md750(the arrays md500 and md501 will assemble).
I found in newer kernels limitation as ("md: disable probing for md devices 512 and over.")

Any idea how I can assemble the array as increase numbering in kernel or safely rename array for assemble?

mdadm: unexpected failure opening /dev/md750

(I have also add a new root disk for a clean install of 16.04 and problem is the same, and a examine of the raid1 disks looks ok.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/346719/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-md-device-mdadm/346742#346742

Comment: I solved it now by moving the md750 array to another system with 14.04 which haven't been running for a year. The array assemble now without problem - my data is back. So array numbering over 512 could be dangerous when you upgrade to 16.04 - newer kernels stop probing md devices over 512.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question (this is encouraged here) and provide the steps you followed so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience.